# Is it possible to select all dishes that contain only ingredients A and B in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know you could achieve this by getting all dishes that contain A and B and then checking every dish in the results with a second query that counts how many ingredients each dish has. Then, if the number is 2, it should be a dish of 2 ingredients that contains A and B, so it ONLY contains A and B. Like this:

Getting all dishes that contain A and B.

```
SELECT dishes.id, dishes.name 
FROM dishes 
JOIN dishes_ingredients ON dishes.id = dishes_ingredients.dishes_id
JOIN ingredients ON dishes_ingredients.ingredients_id = ingredients.id
WHERE ingredients.name IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY dishes.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ingredients.id) = 2;
```

Getting the number of ingredients in each dish.

```
SELECT COUNT(ingredients_id) 
FROM dishes_ingredients 
WHERE dishes_id = (each dish in previous query's results - could be also done in PHP)
```

The problem I see, is that you cannot use in the same query `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ingredients.id)` 2 times, one at the un-selected level, to get the total number of ingredients of a dish, and another at the selected level, to get the number of selected rows given the `WHERE` you used. I guess this is because `HAVING` applies to `GROUP BY`... But maybe I am wrong? If this were possible, then you could check both numbers and get only the dishes that just contain A and B.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even though I accepted the answer by forpas, what I ended doing is more similar to what Gordon Linoff added at the end. So this is what I implemented:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM dishes d
JOIN dishes_ingredients di ON d.id = di.dishes_id
JOIN ingredients i ON di.ingredients_id = i.id
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.name IN ('A', 'B') THEN i.name END) = 2
AND COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `WHERE` clause and set the conditions only in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM dishes d 
JOIN dishes_ingredients di ON d.id = di.dishes_id
JOIN ingredients i ON di.ingredients_id = i.id
GROUP BY d.id, d.name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.name IN ('A', 'B') THEN i.name END) = 2
   AND SUM(i.name NOT IN ('A', 'B')) = 0
```

If each ingredient appears only once for each dish then the `HAVING` clause can be simplified to:

```
HAVING SUM(i.name IN ('A', 'B')) = 2
   AND SUM(i.name NOT IN ('A', 'B')) = 0
```

Another way to do it with the use of `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM dishes d 
JOIN dishes_ingredients di ON d.id = di.dishes_id
JOIN ingredients i ON di.ingredients_id = i.id
GROUP BY d.id, d.name 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.name ORDER BY i.name) = 'A,B'
```

If each ingredient appears only once for each dish then there is no need for `DISTINCT`.

Comment: ... you may also need to add DISTINCT into GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: I don't think that this is necessary. , As I mention in my answer *I assume that each ingredient appears only once for each dish, so there is no need for DISTINCT*

Comment: Actually ingredients do appear more than once (I should have stated that in the question).

Comment: @Pirula more than once for each dish? Why? This is strange.

Comment: Sorry for the strangeness. As Gordon Linoff stated in his answer, HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE... does the job BUT I am still getting dishes that contain ingredients other than A and B.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, COUNT(*) as num_ingredients
FROM dishes d JOIN
     dishes_ingredients di
     ON d.id = di.dishes_id JOIN
     ingredients i
     ON di.ingredients_id = i.id
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING SUM(i.name IN ('A', 'B')) = 2;
```

If the ingredients can be repeated in a recipe, then use:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.name IN ('A', 'B') THEN i.id END) = 2;
```

As with your earlier question, I strongly recommend that you use table aliases in your queries, so they are easier to write and to read.

For only those ingredients, then:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.name IN ('A', 'B') THEN i.id END) = 2 AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) = 2
```

Or, to avoid the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` (which can have poor performance under some circumstances):

```
HAVING SUM(i.name = 'A') > 0 AND
       SUM(i.name = 'B') > 0 AND
       SUM(i.name NOT IN ('A', 'B')) = 0
```

Comment: Why select count(*) as num_ingredients? You are not using it after. When I include that in the query it throws 0 results. When I omitted it, it works but it shows dishes that contain other ingredients as well.

Comment: Ingredients in fact can be repeated, so I tried your answer with COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ... and it does get closer, not selecting dishes that contain 2 times A and no B. The problem is that it still shows dishes that contain other ingredients.

Comment: @Pirula . . . I missed that part of the question, but updated the answer.